# Why is “dont la plupart est...” wrong?

Tags: accord, noms, groupe-nominal

When I gave my French speaking grandmother this sentence -

> À Stratford, il y a beaucoup de restaurants, dont la plupart est delicieux.

Intending to say:

> In Stratford, there are lots of restaurants, of which the majority are delicious.

She said it was wrong, but was unable to tell me why, which is upsetting. Would someone be able to explain why, please? I don't know if the ending should be *sont delicieuses* instead, or is it the *dont la plupart*? Merci.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On peut dire « dont la plupart est délicieuse » (accord grammatical) ou « dont la plupart sont délicieux » (accord sémantique).

Avec des expressions qui désignent un groupe pluriel quantifié par un nom singulier (« la plupart des … », « la majorité des … », « une partie des … », etc.), les deux accords sont acceptés par les grammairiens. Le pluriel est plus fréquent dans les cas comme ici où c'est chaque restaurant qui est délicieux à titre individuel. Le singulier est plus courant dans des cas comme « la moitié des coureurs est arrivée avant l'orage » où l'on parle du groupe dans son ensemble.

En tout cas il faut être cohérent : le verbe et l'attribut du sujet doivent s'accorder avec le même nom, soit *restaurants* (masculin pluriel), soit *plupart* (féminin singulier).

Comment: Quelle phrase pensez-vous soit mieux? Je l'écris pour une affiche, qui est assez formel.

Comment: @user3476093 Dans cette phrase, le pluriel est mieux.

Comment: OK, merci, j'écrirai 'dont la plupart sont delicieuses'

Comment: @user3476093 *délicieux* masculin pluriel, ils s'agit des restaurants (Relire le premier paragraphe de Gilles, en étant attentif : féminin singulier (se réfère à la plupart), masculin pluriel (se réfère aux restaurants)

Comment: @user3476093 Non, justement : « sont délicieux » ou « est délicieuse ». Aucune autre combinaison n'est possible.